# Can one encrypt with a private key/decrypt with a public key?

Tags: cryptography, cookies, openssl, rsa

[Disclaimer: I know, if you know anything about crypto you're probably about to tell me why I'm doing it wrong - I've done enough Googling to know this seems to be the typical response.]

Suppose the following: you have a central authority that wants to issue login cookies for a given domain.  On this domain, you don't necessarily trust everyone, but you have a few key end-points who should be able to read the cookie.  I say a few, but in practice this number of "trusted" partners may be large.  The cookie doesn't contain much information - a username, a timestamp, an expiry, a random number.  It should remain small of course, for performance reasons, even after encryption (within reason).  Now, there are two security issues:

1) We don't trust every webserver on this domain with user data.  For this reason, the ability to read the cookie should be restricted to these trusted partners.
2) While we trust these partners to protect our user's data, we'd still like the central point of authority to be unforgeable (again, within reason).

Now, if we generate a private RSA key for the authority and keep it secret, and distribute the public key only to the "trusted partners", we should be able to encrypt with the private key and have it readable by anyone with the public key.  What I'm unclear on is, would it still be necessary to sign the message, or would the act of decrypting be evidence that it was generated with the private key?  Is this any way in which this scheme would be better or worse than disseminating a symmetric key to all parties involved and using that to encrypt, while using the private key merely to sign?  And of course feel free to tell me all the ways this is a stupid idea, but bear in mind that practical arguments will probably be more convincing than rehashing Alice and Bob.

Oh, and implementation pointers would be welcome, though one can find the basics on Google, if there are any "gotchas" involved that would be useful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use a digital sigantures scheme of some sort, or some other mechanism that is aimed to solve the **integrity** problem of your scenario.

The encryption itself isn't enough.
How would you know that the decrypted messege is what it should be?
Decrypting a cookie encrypted with the right key will surely provide a "valid" cookie, but what happens when you decrypt a cookie encrypted with the wrong key? or just some meaningless data? well, you might just get a cookie that looks valid! (the timestamps are in the range you consider valid, the username is legal, the random number is... uh... a number, etc.).

In most asymmetric encryption algorithms I know off, there is no built-in validation. That means that decrypting a message with the wrong key will not "fail" - it will only give you a wrong plaintext, which **you** must distinguish from a valid plaintext. This is where integrity comes to play, most commonly - using digital signatures.

BTW, RSA is long studied and has several "gotchas", so if you plan to implement it from scratch you better read ahead on how to avoid creating "relatively easy to break" keys.

Comment: Ah, of course!  That makes perfect sense.  Also I'm not planning to re-implement RSA, just going to use the openssl libraries.  So it seems like whether I encrypt with a symmetric key or the private key, I'm going to need a signature anyway.  The question then is, should I just suck it up and distribute another key for the symmetric encryption, or would I lose anything by encrypting with the private key, assuming the set of people who have the public key and would have the symmetric key in this scenario are the same?

Answer (score 20):

Nate Lawson explains [here](http://rdist.root.org/2007/05/01/rsa-public-keys-are-not-private/) and [here](http://rdist.root.org/2007/05/03/rsa-public-keys-are-not-private-implementation/) why you can't securely use the public key as a closely-held secret decryption key (it's a subtle point, and a mistake plenty of others have made before you, so don't feel bad!).

Just use your public key to sign for authenticity, and a separate symmetric key for the secrecy.

I've read enough on interesting attacks against public key systems, and RSA in particular, that I agree absolutely with this conclusion:

> Public key cryptosystems and RSA in
>   particular are extremely fragile. Do
>   not use them differently than they
>   were designed.

(That means: Encrypt with the public key, sign with the private key, and anything else is playing with fire.)

**Addendum:**

If you're interesting in reducing the size of the resulting cookies, you should consider using ECDSA rather than RSA to produce the signatures - ECDSA signatures are considerably smaller than RSA signatures of an equivalent security factor.

Comment: Nate Lawson's reason appears to be the first problem mentioned in Thomas's answer: the e-value for the public key is usually too small to be secret.  To keep your public key secret, you'd need to generate it with a very large random number for its e-value.

Answer (score 6):

In cryptography you are what you know. In your scenario, you have a central authority which is able to issue your cookies, and you want no other entity to be able to do the same. So the central authority must "know" some private data. Also, you want the "trusted web servers" to be able to access the contents of the cookies, and you do not want just anybody do read the cookies. Thus, the "trusted web servers" must also have their own private data.

The normal way would be that the authority applies a digital signature on the cookies, and that the cookies are encrypted with a key known to the trusted web servers. What your are thinking about looks like this:

- There is a RSA modulus *n* and the two usual RSA exponents *d* and *e* (such that *ed = 1* modulo *p-1* and *q-1* where *n=pq*). The central authority knows *d*, the trusted web servers know *e*, the modulus *n* is public.
- The cookie is processed by the central authority by padding it into an integer *c* modulo *n*, and computing *s = c^d* mod *n*.
- The trusted web servers access the cookie data by computing *c = s^e* mod *n*.

Although such a scheme may work, I see the following problems in it:

- For basic security, *e* must be large. In usual RSA descriptions, *e* is the public exponent and is small (like *e = 3*). A small exponent is no problem when it is public, but since you do not want cookie contents to be accessible by third parties, you must make *e* big enough to resist exhaustive search. At the same time, trusted web servers must not know *p* and *q*, only *n*. This means that trusted web servers will need to compute things with a big modulus and a big exponent, and without knowing the modulus factors. This seems a minor point but it disqualifies many RSA implementation libraries. You will be "on your own", with big integers (and all the implementation issues known as "side-channel leaks").
- Resistance of RSA signatures, and resistance of RSA encryption, have been well studied, but not together. It so happens that the padding is essential, and you do not use the same padding scheme for encryption and for signatures. Here, you want a padding scheme which will be good for both signature and encryption. Cryptographers usually consider that good security is achieved when hundreds of trained cryptographers have looked at the scheme for a few years, and found no blatant weakness (or fixed whatever weaknesses were found). Home-cooked schemes almost always fail to achieve security.
- If many people know a secret, then it is not a secret anymore. Here, if all web servers know *e*, then you cannot revoke a trusted web server privileges without choosing a new *e* and communicating the new value to all remaining trusted web servers. You would have that problem with a shared symmetric key too.

The problem of ensuring confidentiality and verifiable integrity in the same type is currently being studied. You may look up [signcryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signcryption). There is no established standard yet.

Basically I think you will be happier with a more classical design, with digital signatures used only for signing, and (symmetric or asymmetric) encryption for the confidentiality part. This will allow you to use existing libraries, with the least possible homemade code.

For the signature part, you may want to use DSA or ECDSA: they yield much shorter signatures (typically 320 bits for a DSA signature of security equivalent to a 1024-bit RSA signature). From the central authority point of view, ECDSA also allows better performance: on my PC, using a single core, OpenSSL crunches out more than 6500 ECDSA signatures per second (in the P-192 NIST curve) and "only" 1145 RSA signatures per second (with a 1024-bit key). The ECDSA signatures consist in two 192-bit integers, i.e. 384 bits to encode, while the RSA signatures are 1024-bit long. ECDSA in P-192 is considered at least as strong, and probably stronger, than RSA-1024.

Answer (score 1):

Public keys are by definition, public. If you're encrypting with a private key and decrypting with a public key, that's not safe from prying eyes. All it says: "this data is coming from person X who holds private key X" and *anyone can verify that, because the other half of the key is public.*

**What's to stop someone you don't trust putting public key X on a server you don't trust?**

If you want a secure line of communication between two servers, you need to have all of those trusted servers have their own public/private key pairs, we'll say key pair Y for one such server.

Server X can then encrypt a message with private key X and public key Y. This says "server X sent a message that only Y could read, and Y could verify it was from X."

(And that message should contain a short-lived symmetric key, because public key crypto is very time-consuming.)

This is what SSL does. It uses public key crypto to set up a session key.

That being said, use a library. This stuff is easy to screw up.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question **"would the act of decrypting be evidence that it was generated with the private key"**, the answer is yes if the recipient can do simple validation of the data. Say you have  "User name : John, timestamp : <number>, expiry : dd/mm/yyyy". Now if a wrong public key is used to decrypt, the probability that you will get "User name : <some letters>, timestamp : <only numbers>, expiry : ??/??/????" is zero. You can validate using a regular expression (regex) like "User name : [a-zA-Z]+, timestamp : [0-9]+, expiry : .... " and drop it validation fails. You can even check if the day is between 1 and 31, month is between 1 and 12 but you won't get to use it as regex will typically fail at "User name : " if wrong public key is used. If validation succeeds you still have to check the timestamp and ensure that you don't have a replay attack.

However, consider the following:

1. RSA public key crypto is not designed for bulk encryption of structured data as it can be exploited by attacker. public key crypto is typically used in 2 ways: 1) for securely transporting the symmetric key (which by definition has no structure) which will be used in bulk encryption; this is done by encrypting the symmetric key using the public key and 2) digitally signing a document by encrypting not the document but the hash of the document (again something which has no structure) using the private key. In your case you are encrypting the cookie which has a definite structure.
2. You are depending on the public key not getting into the hands of the wrong person or entity.
3. public key encryption is about 1000 times slower that symmetric key encryption. This may not be a factor in you case.

If you still want to use this approach, and are able to distribute the public key *only* to the "trusted partners", you should generate a random session key (i.e. symmetric key), encrypt it using the private key and send to all recipients who have the public key. You then encrypt the cookie using the session key. You can change the session key periodically. More infrequently you can change the public key also: you can generate a new public/private key pair and encrypt public key with the session key and send it to all recipients.

Comment: As caf's answer mentions, you can't keep the public key secret with RSA. It is retrieveable from the transmitted messages alone. Don't do this.

Comment: Paulo, I didn't say that you can keep the public key secret with RSA.

Comment: You didn't say this, but your proposal depends on the public key being known only to the recipients. You even say so: *You are depending on the public key not getting into the hands of the wrong person or entity.* And this will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you trust the 'trusted partners' to decrypt and verify the cookie, but don't want them to be able to generate their own cookies? If that's not a problem, you can use a much simpler system: Distribute a secret key to all parties, and use that to both encrypt the cookie and generate an HMAC for it. No need for public key crypto, no need for multiple keys.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to your key distribution approach, which may or may not be suitable in your application, consider using [Kerberos](https://web.mit.edu/kerberos), which uses symmetric key encryption, a single highly protected bastion server that controls all the keying material, and a clever set of protocols (See the [Needham-Schroder protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needham%E2%80%93Schroeder_protocol))