# OpenSSL: PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE

Tags: windows, openssl, certificate, trusted

I need a hash-name for file for posting in Stunnel's CApath directory. I have got some certs in this directory and they are working well. Also, I have a server sert and server key:

```
cert = c:\Program Files (x86)\stunnel\server_cert.pem 
key = c:\Program> Files (x86)\stunnel\private\server_key.pem
```

When I try to calculate a hash of my new cert, I get an error:

```
/etc/pki/tls/misc/c_hash cert.pem

unable to load certificate 140603809879880:error:0906D06C:PEM
routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

As I understand I must sign my cert, but I don't understand how I can do that. 
Please, provide the solution.

P.S.:

The message

```
unable to load certificate 140603809879880:error:0906D06C:PEM
routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE:
```

posted when I made **c_hash** for **cert.pem** This is not server_cert.pem, this is Root_CA and it is content something like

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----  
...6UXBNSDVg5rSx60=.. 

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

When I write

```
openssl x509 -noout -text -in cert.pem
```

In console panel I see this info:

```
    Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 1 (0x1)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=BE, ST=BB, L=BB, O=BANKSYS NV, OU=SCY, CN=TEST Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: May 31 08:06:40 2005 GMT
            Not After : May 31 08:06:40 2020 GMT
        Subject: C=BE, ST=BB, L=BB, O=BB NV, OU=SCY, CN=TEST Root CA
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:82:c8:58:1e:e5:7a:b2:63:a6:15:bd:f9:bb:1f:
............
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                76:70:AB:92:9B:B1:26:CE:9E:93:D8:77:4F:78:0D:B8:D4:6C:DA:C6
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         2c:7e:bd:3f:da:48:a4:df:8d:7c:96:58:f7:87:bd:e7:16:24:
...............
```

Comment: Might help someone else, I got this error when I wrongly swapped `key` and `cert` files in `https` config object provided to `webpack.config`'s `devServer`.

Comment: Thanks @tao. That's exactly what happened to me working with suds. I swapped both files. It still doesn't work, but at least I got rid of this error ;p

Answer (score 55):

1. Since you are on Windows, make sure that your certificate in Windows "compatible", most importantly that it doesn't have `^M` in the end of each line

   If you open it it will look like this:

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----^M
   MIIDITCCAoqgAwIBAgIQL9+89q6RUm0PmqPfQDQ+mjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBM^M
   ```

   To solve "this" open it with `Write` or Notepad++ and have it convert it to Windows "style"
2. Try to run `openssl x509 -text -inform DER -in server_cert.pem` and see what the output is, it is unlikely that a private/secret key would be untrusted, trust only is needed if you exported the key from a keystore, did you?

Comment: Try to run this `openssl x509 -hash -noout -in` it does hash extraction, see if it helps?

Comment: that's useful. Thanks. But in STunnel log I see the error `SSL_accept: 14094418: error:14094418:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert unknown ca
Connection reset: 0 byte(s) sent to SSL, 0 byte(s) sent to socket` when I try ro make connection

Comment: That means something else altogether, it means that both sides are not using the same `ca` for their CA certificate

Comment: Thanks, `openssl x509 -text -inform DER -in server_cert.pem` converted my `p7b` encoded(?) certificate to something usable.

Comment: My problem wasn't CRLF line endings as described here, but this suggestion was enough to get me on track.  My problem was the my file was saved double-byte Unicode with a BOM, and openssl for windows couldn't deal with that.  I resaved as ascii and it worked.

Comment: Thanks @ElroyFlynn, that was my problem too — openssl on Linux has the same trouble if there's a BOM at the beginning of the file.

Comment: +1. In my case, the problem (once I looked carefully) was that I actually had a certificate *request* (`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----`) rather than a certificate (`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----`). I was able to inspect it by using `openssl req ...` rather than `openssl x509 ...`.

Comment: For anyone else who has this error, my problem was that I was running the command to convert .p7b to .cer as `openssl pkcs7 -in pkcs7.p7b -print_certs > pem.cer`, the solution was to use `-out` instead of `>`, so `openssl pkcs7 -in pkcs7.p7b -print_certs -out pem.cer`

Comment: No need for -text parameter

Answer (score 55):

Another possible cause of this is trying to use the ;x509; module on something that is not X.509.

The server certificate is X.509 format, but the private key is RSA.

So:

```
openssl rsa -noout -text -in privkey.pem
openssl x509 -noout -text -in servercert.pem
```

Answer (score 23):

My mistake was simply using the CSR file instead of the CERT file.

Comment: at least i am not the only one who made this mistake...  i am surprised the module does not alert us to this.

Comment: this took me hours to work out. All starting with a cryptic error from xmlsec1, `key is not found`

Answer (score 16):

My situation was a little different. The solution was to strip the .pem from everything outside of the CERTIFICATE and PRIVATE KEY sections and to invert the order which they appeared.
After converting from pfx to pem file, the certificate looked like this:

```
Bag Attributes
localKeyID: ...
issuer=...
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
Bag Attributes
more garbage...
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

After correcting the file, it was just:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: M kinda noob, pls suggest me..How to edit this file in mac

Comment: I had a similar error.  Inverting the order worked for me.

Comment: My keys came in seperate files I needed to create a new file: `cat $SOURCE/privkey.pem $SOURCE/fullchain.pem > server.pem`

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue using Windows, got if fixed by opening it in Notepad++ and changing the encoding from "UCS-2 LE BOM" to "UTF-8".

Answer (score 8):

Change encoding in notepad++ **UTF-8 with BOM**. That is how it worked for me

Comment: Yes! This worked for me. Note PEM certificates exported from Apple's Keychain utility don't have the BOM and this upsets some programs.

Answer (score 7):

You can get this misleading error if you *naively* try to do this:

```
[clear] -> Private Key Encrypt -> [encrypted] -> Public Key Decrypt -> [clear]
```

**Encrypting data using a private key is not allowed by design**.

You can see from the [command line options for open ssl](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities) that the only options to `encrypt -> decrypt` go in one direction `public -> private`.

```
  -encrypt        encrypt with public key
  -decrypt        decrypt with private key
```

The other direction is intentionally prevented because public keys basically "can be guessed." So, encrypting with a private key means the only thing you gain is verifying the author has access to the private key.

The `private key encrypt -> public key decrypt` direction is called "signing" to differentiate it from being a technique that can actually secure data.

```
  -sign           sign with private key
  -verify         verify with public key
```

*Note: my description is a simplification for clarity. [Read this answer for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7151033/768963).*