# openssl self signed certificate node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl

I have installed openSSl with cygwin and generated self singed certifikate like this

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048

openssl req -new -key server.key -out csr.pem

openssl x509 -req -in csr.pem -signkey server.key -out cert.pem
```

i tried to test if i was succesfull so i created a basic tls connection with node

```
var tls=require("tls");
var fs=require("fs");
var serverOptions={
    key:fs.readFileSync('C:/cygwin64/home/Matej/csr.pem'),
    cert:fs.readFileSync('C:/cygwin64/home/Matej/cert.pem')
}
var server=tls.createServer(serverOptions);
server.listen(4001)
```

but it threw error

```
        c.context.setKey(options.key);
                  ^
Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

i quite dont understand what does the erron mean. Did i generated the key/certifikate wrong?

I tried looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837161/openssl-pem-routinespem-read-biono-start-linepem-lib-c703expecting-truste) but my pem files does not contain ^M .My cert looks like

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
and csr

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

Comment: The key should be `server.key` and not `csr.pem`

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenSSL: PEM routines:PEM\_read\_bio:no start line:pem\_lib.c:703:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837161/openssl-pem-routinespem-read-biono-start-linepem-lib-c703expecting-truste)

Comment: that link does not solve my problem