# how can i solve npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, npm, error-handling, npm-install, rethinkdb

I'm new to Node.js. I tried to add RethinkDB module to my project, but I got: `npm error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line` error.

[image]

I don't use a proxy, tried uninstalling/reinstalling Node.js, and changing the registry from the solutions I found online, but none of them worked.

Comment: Since you are on windows, it is likely that there is a problem with your certificate format, or you are providing the wrong path.

Comment: I can install it to the nodejs folder. But shouldn't I also install it to the project's folder?

Comment: Do you mean that you can install it globally but not locally?

Comment: Yes, I can install anything globally but locally i can't install anything.

Comment: Can you maybe uninstall the global version, and delete the node_modules directory in your project and reinstall locally?

Comment: I did what you recommend but still not able to install locally. Is there a workaround to use glabol module on the local folder?

Comment: Just add the path to your `PATH` environment variable. Here's a helpful post to achieve that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27864040/fixing-npm-path-in-windows-8-and-10/27864331

Comment: I add the path but now I get the error;                                                             
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/bluebird
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'bluebird@>= 2.3.2 < 3' is not in the npm registry.

Comment: I tried it and it works just fine. Maybe try to change this to `bluebird@3.0` or to `bluebird@^2.3.2` depending on whether you know the exact version or not.

Answer (score 5):

type this line `npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` and after that try again

I assume that your certificate is expired

Answer (score 1):

that what solved for me on windows ,

cmd:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -m PEM -f jwtRS256.key
# Don't add passphrase
openssl rsa -in jwtRS256.key -pubout -outform PEM -out jwtRS256.key.pub
```

then on cmd:

```
more jwtRS256.key
```

then copy privatekey to your config file , then:

put on every new line:

```
  /n
```

before :

```
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
    MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAlFVXSZ6llZItgZ0JaiyD7PO3l+b7PPqtt0U3iVyTs0qhEWJB
    Sa7nvyqth2Z+vOVuT5p97GJQ3nMx5CRQsF73YHdFFdUzfIDgFYOiPRT4pAw4l05r
```

after (on config json):

```
    "JWTPRIVATEKEY":"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n
    MIIJKAIBAAKCAgEAlFVXSZ6llZItgZ0JaiyD7PO3l+b7PPqtt0U3iVyTs0qhEWJB\n
    Sa7nvyqth2Z+vOVuT5p97GJQ3nMx5CRQsF73YHdFFdUzfIDgFYOiPRT4pAw4l05r\n
    ....d8ul170=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

then trim spaces:

```
    "JWTPRIVATEKEY": "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\nMI.............d8ul170=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----",
```

then do the same with public key..

```
 more jwtRS256.key.pub
```

smile