# Issues when installing `surge` using npm installer

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Please have a look on error I'm getting.

```
C:\Users\softech>npm install --global surge
npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE
npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line`

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\softech\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-09T10_06_15_297Z-debug.log

C:\Users\softech>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! No one here will solve your issue directly. Try to put more information, like debug.log file.

Comment: Have you looked at solutions suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57194920/cant-install-express-because-npm-install-express-error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i solve npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM in Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55236936/how-can-i-solve-npm-err-error0909006cpem-in-node-js)