# npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE and routines:get_name:no start line when installing ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I was trying to install react, but it keeps saying aborting installation I'm using node v16-14-0 npm v6-14-11.

```sh
npx creat-react-app my-app
npx: installed 67 in 13.6s

creating a new react app in C:\User\adminstrator\my-app.
npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE
npm ERR! error:0909006c:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:User\adminstrator\my-app\_logs\2021-03-18T12_17_27_469Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-script cra-template has failed.
Deleting generated file... package.json
```

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61100532/2873538) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56561186/2873538). Also, [this](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/16116#issuecomment-288782409)

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete .npmrc from C:\Users{username}. This worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I also got this kind of error before and uninstalling and deleting all node related files solved the problem.

1 - Uninstall nodejs from Programs & Features with the uninstaller.

2 - Delete these files:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Nodejs

C:\Program Files\Nodejs

C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm

C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache

C:\Users\{User}\.npmrc (and possibly check for that without the . prefix too)
```

3 - Or you can do this

```
npm clear cache
```

then, again check for these files if they are not deleted and
delete these files

```
C:\User\user\appdata\roaming\npm-cache

C:\User\user\appdata\roaming\npm

C:\User\user\appdata\Local\Temp

C:\programefile\nodejs
```

4 - go to this  C:\User{user} and then unhide it if it was hidden and delete .**npmrc** file and delete all reated file to it(about 4 or 5 files)

5 - if it is uninstalled successfully (you can check with **node --version**) then reboot your computer

6 - Then, type this command

```
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

7 - and finally you're good to go

```
npx create-react-app app_name 
   or 
npm install <package-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem when i tried to create new react app

solution: just go to this address  << C:\Users\omar >>
[omar is my user name for you its what your user name is]
and at the bottom you would see a file with the name of << .npmrc >> and delete it

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting that problem, the cause in all cases is something related to any certificate that uses any app that we are building. In my case, I was able to solve the error by doing this:

1. Install `mkcert`: `brew install mkcert`
2. Run the next command `npm run setup-https`.
3. Create a host entry in your local hosts file, `/etc/hosts` for [local-site-url] pointing to localhost:

```
[local-site-url] dev.new.expensify.com
```

P.D: Open vim using sudo like sudo vim /etc/hosts/