# unable to install angular cli using npm on windows 10

Tags: angular-cli

I'm trying to install angular on windows 10 using command line " npm install -g @angular/cli" but it won't , it show me error:

npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_PEM_NO_START_LINE
npm ERR! error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\administrateur\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-09-27T12_55_53_805Z-debug-0.log

can anybody help please , first time it was installed successfully but when i create new angular app it show me error:
the schematic workflow failed. see above
so i tried to download other version of node and angular then i used yarn and now it won't even work

Comment: to "create" a new angular app you use: `ng new myapp` (this create your app in the directory `myapp`) -see the [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0)- see that you execute the command in a directory that has no angular.json-

Comment: i know , but angular won't even install , "npm install -g @angular/cli"  ,

Comment: What version is node and npm do you have installed on that machine?

Comment: Look this post, i think it can help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66691292/npm-err-code-err-ossl-pem-no-start-line-and-routinesget-nameno-start-line-whe

Comment: node version : v16.17.1 , npm version : 8.15.0

Comment: when i enter to the file in the path , that's it :                                                                       0 verbose cli C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
1 info using npm@8.15.0
2 info using node@v16.17.1
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 13ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 14ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 3ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1m

Answer (score 0):

for me it was a the .npmrc file , you can find it in c:\users\name , i deleted that file then install angular localy with yarn not npm and everything is work
ps: before every angular commande i use yarn because angular installed locally[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6V9g.jpg)