# I am not able to get signed url in cloudfront, getting fatal error, code I am trying is below

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

```
<?php

require '../aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient;
use Aws\Exception\AwsException;

// Create a CloudFront Client
$client = new Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
]);

// Set up parameter values for the resource
$resourceKey = 'https://example.cloudfront.net/b20cbfe5-a8df-47a5-94c4-aeadea20759f/dash/videoplayback.mpd';
$expires = time() + 300;

// Create a signed URL for the resource using the canned policy
$signedUrlCannedPolicy = $client->getSignedUrl([
    'url' => $resourceKey,
    'expires' => $expires,
    'private_key' => 'pk.pem',
    'key_pair_id' => 'keyid'
]);
```

getting error as

Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line in C:\xampp\htdocs\aws\Aws\CloudFront\Signer.php:40 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\aws\Aws\CloudFront\UrlSigner.php(24): Aws\CloudFront\Signer->__construct('APKAJYH2L6BGHLW...', 'pk-APKAJYH2L6BG...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\aws\Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient.php(138): Aws\CloudFront\UrlSigner->__construct('APKAJYH2L6BGHLW...', 'pk-APKAJYH2L6BG...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\aws\app\stream.php(26): Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient->getSignedUrl(Array) #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\aws\Aws\CloudFront\Signer.php on line 40

Comment: Your private key file is probably not formatted right.

Comment: how do I check that?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837161/openssl-pem-routinespem-read-biono-start-linepem-lib-c703expecting-truste

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue. The issue was you need to give absolute path in below like this

```
'private_key' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/' . 'pk.pem',
```

Let me know if it's working or not?