# Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.InvalidCypherTextException: pad block corrupted (C# .net core 5)

Tags: c#, .net-core, encryption, bouncycastle

I have a private key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,35E517D660EB89EC
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The encrypted private key has a passphrase `test1234`

This code fails with `pad block corrupted`:

```
string rsaPrivateKey = @"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: DES-EDE3-CBC,35E517D660EB89EC
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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

TextReader textReader = new StringReader(rsaPrivateKey);
PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(textReader, new PasswordFinder("test1234"));
object privateKeyObject = pemReader.ReadObject(); // Error Here
Console.WriteLine(privateKeyObject.ToString());
```

I saw here ([C# Bouncy Castle decoding private key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46103923/5660649)) a similar question, but I have no unicode characters in my passphrase.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is an encrypted private key in PKCS#1 format, which is not supported, but only PKCS#8 format (-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----). A conversion is possible e.g. with OpenSSL.

Comment: Thank you! That will get me on my way

Comment: Why is the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/q/46103923/5660649 suggesting that PKCS#1 would work then?

Comment: Oops, I may have been a bit hasty here and done BC/C# an injustice. Probably there is just a problem with this particular key or the password is wrong. `openssl rsa -check -noout -passin pass:test1234 -in <path to key file>` returns an error for this key.

Comment: Thank you! That appears to be the issue. I was told this was the password to this key, but it is obviously not.