# Generating RSA public key from its private key counter part in Web Crypto API

Tags: cryptography, rsa, webcrypto-api

I thought this would be a simple matter but it looks like webcrypto api doesn't provide a way to take a private key and generate its public key counterpart.

Is this true? Or am I missing something?

The reason I'm trying to do this is because I want to transfer the keypair and trying to reduce the total size. It would be great if I can just export the private key and later retrieve both of the pairs.

Comment: Sounds like you're stressing over an insignificant savings of a few hundred bytes at most.

Comment: People have reasons for doing things they do. Just because you don't understand why, doesn't mean other they are stupid. In my case I *do* have a need to reduce the size as much as possible. I wish I could go without worrying about this either.

Comment: Settle down, I'm required by law to point these things out.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test this but you can try `exportKey()` with `spki` format and then importing that with `importKey()` with `spki` format. Hopefully the `exportKey('spki', <private key>)` will only export the public part and not throw a TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

WebCrypto does not provide a mechanism to derive the public key from a private key.

It is technically possible with the RSA cryptosystem but not necessarily others (see [Given a private key, is it possible to derive its public key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696472/given-a-private-key-is-it-possible-to-derive-its-public-key)) you are only missing `e` which is generally could be brute forced/guessed (it is usually 65537).

Migrating private keys is something you do not want to do often if at all, every place a software key exists it may leave a remnant (page file, etc) that could be used to discover key later.

If you make the private key exportable (you do not want to do this for security reasons -- see above why) then you could write javascript to do this.

In short, the space savings is probably not worth the complexity and security consequences.