# can private key decrypt message encrypted using itself?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, private, public-key-encryption, private-key

i was studying asymmetric encryption and i have a question about this encryption , i know that i can use public key to drcrypt message encrypted using private key and i can use private key to drcrypt message encrypted using private key.

but i was wondering if there is an ability to be using private key to decrypt message is encrypted using itself (private key)?

because i read that the private key is the complete key and you can extract the public key from it , but i searched about this thing but i have not found any decisive answer until now.

Comment: Sometimes the public key is stored together with the private key ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a private key, is it possible to derive its public key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696472/given-a-private-key-is-it-possible-to-derive-its-public-key)

Comment: There are multiple different asymmetric crypto systems. Is your question targeting a specific one like RSA or elleptic curves? Because I don't think the properties of all asymmetric crypto systems are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, as public key can be derived from private key but the vice versa is not possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).